# How can I get argparse to recognize a positional argument which follows a variable length optional argument?

Tags: python, argparse, optional-parameters, positional-argument

I am writing a script that will be used to merge several input files, generating a single output file, and I want to build a small command line interface using [`argparse`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html).  To me, the most natural-seeming way to do it would be to have a single optional input, `-i`, which takes one or more input file names, followed by a positional argument, representing the output file name.  Here's an example of what I had in mind:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
"""
Script for merging input files
"""
import argparse

script_docstring = 'Read some input files and create a merged output.'
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description=script_docstring)
# Optional input file names
parser.add_argument('-i --inputs', nargs='+', type=str, required=True,
                    help='Input file names', dest='inputs')
# Positional output file name
parser.add_argument('fname_out', type=str, help='Output file name')
args = parser.parse_args()

# Display what the user chose at the command line
print(args.inputs)
print(args.fname_out)
```

When I print the auto-generated help message created by `argparse`, the call signature looks like what I had intended:

```
> ./mergefiles.py --help
usage: mergefiles.py [-h] -i --inputs INPUTS [INPUTS ...] fname_out

Read some input files and create a merged output.

positional arguments:
  fname_out             Output file name

optional arguments:
  -h, --help            show this help message and exit
  -i --inputs INPUTS [INPUTS ...]
                        Input file names
```

However, when I actually attempt to run the script, it gives an error which suggests to me that `argparse` is mistakenly parsing the final positional argument as though it were to be included amongst the list of optionals:

```
> ./mergefiles.py -i a.in b.in c.in test.out
usage: mergefiles.py [-h] -i --inputs INPUTS [INPUTS ...] fname_out
mergefiles.py: error: the following arguments are required: fname_out
```

**My question:** Is it even possible to get `argparse` to handle a case such as this correctly, treating the final argument as a positional?  Or is my only option to accept a "workaround" solution such as turning the output file name into an optional argument as well, e.g., like `-f --fname_out` or similar.

If it's not possible to do what I want, then I plan to implement exactly that as my fallback solution.  However, before I accept an inelegant workaround, I'm curious whether it's actually possible to get `argparse` to handle this the "correct" way.

Comment: No you can't trick `argparse` into handling this.  Because of the `+`, `inputs` gets all the remaining strings, leaving none for `fname_out`.  Ideally it should do some sort of 'look-ahead' and reserve one for the positional, but the current code doesn't do that.  Putting the positional string first should work: 'test.out -i a b c'

Comment: Yes, some type of lookahead capability (I suppose this would be similar to what exists in some [regular expression engines](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)) is sort of what I had in mind.  Thanks for confirming that it's not implemented, and that there's therefore no secret technique for triggering it.

Answer (score 5):

When using a positional as the last argument you must use -- to separate the arguments:

```
python3 args.py -i infile1 infile2 -- outfile
['infile1', 'infile2']
outfile
```

I hope this helps

Comment: Thanks--this does indeed work as advertised, and the double dash input technique for separating arguments ("--") is something that I wasn't aware of, so yes, it was helpful.  However, I would also categorize this solution as sort of a workaround too, just one of a different type.

Comment: @stachyra : The double dash `--` is not a workaround, it's a feature :-) `man bash` says that it signifies the end of the options, and after it only positional arguments are allowed. See e.g. https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/187548/266189 .